# Let $p(x)$ be irreducible in $K[x]$ & $p(x)|(r_1(x)...r_n(x))$ where $r_i(x) \in K[x] \forall 1 \leq i \leq n$. Then $p(x)|r_i(x)$ ...

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

**Theorem.** Let $p(x)$ be irreducible in $K[x]$ and $p(x)|(r_1(x)...r_n(x))$ where $r_i(x) \in K[x]$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$. Then $p(x)|r_i(x)$ for at least one $1 \leq i \leq n $.

**Proof.** I read that the proof should be by induction on $n$, but I don't understand how to do this, what's the given formula that you usually substitute values of $n$ into? I just don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since any irreducible element in $K[X]$ is also prime, we have that $p\mid r_1\cdots r_n$ implies that $p\mid r_i$ for some $i$. Formally, we could do induction on $n$, the case $n=1$ being trivial.

Comment: How do we know that it's a PID?

Comment: How do we know that? It is [well-known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531256/for-a-field-k-is-there-a-way-to-prove-that-kx-is-a-pid-without-mentioning) :) But we don't need it.